# ¿Es importante poner usar EventQueue.invokeLater en mi metodo main?

Tags: java

Cree una clase heredada de `JFrame` y la mando llamar en otra clase con este codigo

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                JFrameEjemplo window = new JFrameEjemplo();
                window.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Mi pregunta va relacionada a que si es necesario incorporar todo ese codigo o solo con este código es necesario:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            JFrameEjemplo window = new JFrameEjemplo();
            window.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El procesamiento completo de Swing se realiza en un hilo llamado **EDT (Event Dispatching Thread).** Por lo que de la forma tradiconal podría bloquear este hilo, ya que tu programa implicitamente lo está usando (con Swing).

Por ese motivo la manera de asegurar que la GUI no sea bloqueada es usar la forma que comentas al inicio:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

}

Con esto aseguras que tu aplicación sea ejecutada en otro hilo (thread para los amigos).

Saludos!